# How to extract value from async method and put value in apolloProvider variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, lazy-loading

I want extract value from async method `extractZMockClient` and put this value in apolloProvider variable in properties: defaultClient and clients.

**I already do that, but on `console.log(apolloProvider())` I got that:** 
[image]

```js
const ZMockClient = async () => import("z-mock-client")

const extractZMockClient = async () => {
    try {
        const callZMockClient = await ZMockClient()
        return callZMockClient.mockedClient
    } catch (ex) {
        throw new Error(ex)
    }
}

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: MOCKED_UI ? extractZMockClient() : v2,
    clients: {
        v2: MOCKED_UI ? extractZMockClient() : v2
    }
})
```

Comment: If `VueApollo` doesn't accept a promise as an argument, you will need to make the whole `apolloProvider` a promise. Why are you immediately instantiating that anyway, if you say you want to lazy-load the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extractZMockClient has implicitly a promise returned that resolves with your returned value. To get your value use

```
extractZMockClient().then(function(result){ 
    // create your apollo
})
```

result corresponds to your return in extractZMockClient

Recomendation: throw away the extract and just use

```
ZMockClient().then((response)=>{ 
    // dostuff
}).catch((error)=>{console.error(error)})
```

since you use it with await it returns a promise ;)

Comment: There's no need to change syntax as the `await` expression waits for the promise to be resolved and evaluates as the resolved value. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: this is indeed possible as long it's used inside an async function

Comment: I'm not sure if @kikosko actually likes them XD

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing an `await` here:

```js
const ZMockClient = async () => await import("z-mock-client")
```